# Any workarounds for Microsoft SkyDrive 20,000 file limit?

Tags: onedrive

I have three users who are subscribed to Microsoft Office 365 Small Business Premium. They are using the SkyDrive Pro that comes in the package. We've hit the 20,000 file limit that Microsoft imposes.

Has anyone found a workaround for this, so that more than 20,000 files can be stored?

Comment: Its a hard limit.  Have you contacted Microsoft about this problem since your a paid Skydrive customer you get support.

Comment: How about creating a virtual disk that you can mount.  That should only occupy 1 file entry?  Truecrypt is a good option and I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: Not a great solution, but we have created some "Sites" in 365. These appear in SkyDrive under the "Sharepoint" folder. Each appears to have it's own 5,000 file limit, so by dividing the data up a bit, we're able to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could always zip/archive files that you may not need on a regular basis to combine multiple files into one.

Comment: Thanks - I should have made the original question more explicit. We need the ability to share files from one SkyDrive to another, so can't easily wrap the 20K files in a container of any kind. I'll contact Microsoft support to see if there is anything they can suggest

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft seems to have removed this limit since the question was asked.  I currently have 34,585 files in my Photos folder alone. (This is with an Office 365 Home account.)

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why I didn't make this an answer.. but:

(From my comments to OP)

How about creating a virtual disk that you can mount. That should only occupy 1 file entry? Truecrypt is a good option and I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: -1 Skydrive can not do delta sync.

Comment: Hm, the question wasn't about saving delta's - it was about storing more than 20k files - unfair downvote imo.

Comment: Skydrive can not do delta sync, which means that **the entire VHD will need to be retransmitted each time a file is changed**

Comment: Again, the original question was about storing more than 20k files. Using this method you *CAN* store more than 20k files inside the container - the practicalities around that were not made clear until after I posted the answer.  *BUT* this *WILL* work.

Comment: No this will not work. You will not be able to sync the files before you unmount the VHD, and even then it will take hours to upload. Also see [OP’s comment](http://superuser.com/questions/678423/any-workarounds-for-microsoft-skydrive-20-000-file-limit/678717?noredirect=1#comment859419_678453).

Comment: I assume you've tried this? I have and I can confirm, that although it does take a long time, it *DOES* work.  And as I said .. the OP's comments were added *AFTER* my response.